# C# MySQLDriverCS - ' characters in insert/update

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using MySQLDriverCS to connect my C# program with a MySQL database.

Everything is going well except when I want to run an insert/update query where one of the values contains a `'` character.

MySQL wants to escape the `'` character with a single `\`, i.e. `\'`

But I can't make C# allow me to escape the character the same way. When I try `\\'`, it ends up in the database as `\\' =>` the query fails with an exception.

Query example:

```
UPDATE products SET brand = 'L'Occitane', product = 'Test' WHERE id = 435
```

=> SQL exception

Trying replace:

```
text = text.Replace("\'", "\\'");
UPDATE products SET brand = 'L\\'Occitane', product = 'Test' WHERE id = 435
```

=> SQL exception

Comment: Good idea. I have added queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does better when you escape apostrophes in text strings by doubling them, rather than by prefixing them with backslash.

So, try this.

```
UPDATE products SET brand = 'L''Occitane', product = 'Test' WHERE id = 435
```

But you would be better off using bind variables. That way you could avoid having to deal with string-escaping monkey business for your application's data.

The Connector.NET connector does well with this bind variable stuff.